# How can I resolve the accesibility error for "Have an accessible name" on a toast?

Tags: html, accessibility, toast

What is the correct way to resolve this error on a toast (popup notification)?
eg name? aria-labelledby?
Is the to describe what is in the notification or what the component is?

I'm using https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast

This renders something like this

```
<div role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div tabindex="0">
        <button type="button" aria-label="Close">×</button>
        <div>
            <p>Some notification text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using some framework or plain HTML? Please add relevant code

Comment: @TusharShahi apologies! Added relevant code and details of used framework

Comment: Note that your `aria-live` is superfluous since `role="alert"` already gives you an `assertive` region.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `<div tabindex="0">`?  Why does the user need to tab to the container?  I think that's the crux of the problem.  If you're using a scanning tool such as axe or wave and you're getting that error, it's probably seeing that an element can receive focus (tabindex=0) but that element does not have an accessible name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the two ways to resolve it:

1. if you have a specific HTML element that holds the title of the toast, give the element an id and use the id as the value  of `aria-labelledby` in the parent elementNode e.g

```
<div aria-labelledby="title" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <h3 id="title">I am the title</h3>
  ...
</div>
```

2. you can just use the `aria-label` attribute on the parent nodeElement e,g:

```
<div aria-label="Your subscription is about to expire" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  ...
</div>
```

In summary, what this does is; it tells the screen-reader what the pop-up is about as a kind of summary just the way we get a quick grasp of what an input field is all about when a label is added.

Comment: Using `aria-labelledby` is generally the "best practice" approach if there's already an element on the page that contains the text you need (such as the `<h2>`).

Comment: Addendum to slugolicious' already excellent comments, if you plan on going with `aria-label` rather than `aria-labeledby` - ask yourself why sighted users wont benefit from a visible title. For a smaller alert such as this, the notification text itself can often work as the accessible name, so you don't need to dream up an additional, potentially redundant heading.

Answer (score 0):

For users using a screen reader, there is no title for this alert. With a title, the screen reader announces to the user what is the new content about.

`aria-labelledby` or `aria-describedby` can be used to point to an element to be used as a title for the alert.

If you do not want to add a heading that is visible, just make an invisible heading and point to it.

```css
h2{
font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h2>XXX</h2>
```

```
<div role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <h2>Your title</h2>
    <div tabindex="0">
        <button type="button" aria-label="Close">×</button>
        <div>
            <p>Some notification text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
h2{
font-size: 0px;
}
```